# Where col is equal to x return next ordered value in list - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm hoping to parse through a df and return specific rows based on a condition. Specifically, for Col `String`, where equal to `A`, I'm hoping to return the next subsequent row that is equal to either `'B','C' or 'D'`. If none of these values exist before the next A then I'm hoping to return a message stating `No item found for:` *ID String* or something similar.

Note: Using `isin` isn't applicable here:

```
Item = ['A','B','C','D']

df = df[df['String'].isin(Item)]
```

Because I only want to return the **first** string of `'B','C' or 'D'` that appears after `A`. I don't want **all** of these strings wherever they appear. I also want to determine if A exists but isn't followed by `'B','C' or 'D'` before the next `A`.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'String' : ['A','F','B','C','D','A','X','C','B','D','A','Y','A','C','A','D','C','B'],                  
    'ID' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18],                         
        })

mask = df1.loc[df1['String'] == 'A', 'ID']

# Next value required
# Something like. where mask == True find next row equal to val in item list.
# If None: print(No item found for: ID)
item = ['B','C','D']
```

Intended output:

```
   String  ID
0       A   1
2       B   3
5       A   6
7       C   8
10      A  11
12      A  13
13      C  14
14      A  15
15      D  16

No item found for: ID 11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution, a couple of steps for clarity:

```
df1["is_a"] = df1.String == "A"
df1["a_group"] = df1.is_a.cumsum()

def foo(s):
    matches = s[s.String.isin(["B", "C", "D"]) ]
    if len(matches):
        return s.loc[[s.index[0], matches.index[0]]]
    else: 
        print(f"No match for A in location {s.index[0]}")
    
    
df1.groupby("a_group").apply(foo)
```

The output is:

```
No match for A in location 10

           String  ID   is_a  a_group
a_group                              
1       0       A   1   True        1
        2       B   3  False        1
2       5       A   6   True        2
        7       C   8  False        2
4       12      A  13   True        4
        13      C  14  False        4
5       14      A  15   True        5
        15      D  16  False        5
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `shift`

```
item = ['A', 'B','C','D']
     
# filter df
df1 = df1.loc[df1.String.isin(item)]

# find missing ID's using shift
for line in df1[(df1.String == 'A') & (df1.String.shift(-1) =='A')].iterrows():
    print(f'No item found for: ID {line[1].ID}')

# find final df using shift
print(df1.loc[(df1.String == 'A') | ((df1.String.shift(1) == 'A') & (df1.String.isin(item)))])

#prints

No item found for: ID 11

   String  ID
0       A   1
2       B   3
5       A   6
7       C   8
10      A  11
12      A  13
13      C  14
14      A  15
15      D  16
```